# Typescript returns execSync as undefined from the child_process module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript1.7

I'm trying to use the function execSync from the module child_process.

But when I import the module:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../GENERAL/d.ts/node/node.d.ts" />
var execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
```

And try to use the function I get an exception saying that `execSync` is undefined.

I even tried to print the module to check the functions that are being imported and I got this result:

```
{ fork: [Function],
  _forkChild: [Function],
  exec: [Function],
  execFile: [Function],
  spawn: [Function] }
```

The d.ts file that's being used is the following one:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

Comment: Do you need to upgrade node? What version are you at?

Comment: Hi @MicahWilliamson. I'm using the version v0.10.25.

Comment: Try using the definitions in [`node-0.10.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node-0.10.d.ts) to match your version of Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your node version is at `0.10.25` I think you need to upgrade node. The first line of the definition file says `// Type definitions for Node.js v4.x`

To upgrade node run this command-

```
sudo npm install -g n
```